# Administrative shares

Tags: windows-7, privacy-protection

I found out recently that work is scanning employee e-mails and accessing our Laptops/Desktops through Administrative shares. I have nothing to hide but see this as an invasion of privacy and liberty.

I would like to disable these if possible. I have admin rights on my laptop which is running windows 7.

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: While it is certainly possible, if this is a work computer, they likely have it open for IT reasons. For example, I push out updates every day, and they go on the ADMIN$ share, and get launched from there. I'd recommend talking to your manager or IT staff first.

Comment: Most workplaces state that employees have no expectation of privacy (and certainly no self-declared liberties) in policy and employee training. Be careful how much privilege you assert. Also, be aware, in most work networks, admin staff can easily reenable admin shares on every boot, with group policies.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, you probably *shouldn't* do that, but... 
If you wanted to, you could take the settings they have for the share, write them down, type them in notepad, whatever works (share name especially important). Remove the existing share, then create your own with the exact same name and location. Set your security to allow only you access rights. I could be wrong, but I don't think even Group Policy will over-write a share like this. This would still leave the share, but only you would be able to access it. However, if they notice, they could revoke your local admin rights, remote into your computer, and change everything back, or just give themselves rights to it again.